# zend framework access custom properties of model in view

Tags: php, zend-framework

I defined a custom property in my model that is an array:

```
protected $_types;
```

It's returned to view a collection of objects model as array, with array $_types inside.

My question is how i can access this property in view?

In view, i created a foreach to show each object:

```
<?php foreach ($this->results as $item)
```

So how to access to each position of this array ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return value(s) [ array of values or object ] to Controller from Model and then from Controller you have to assign to view variables to use on View page.

I hope this way would works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the scope of variable $_type as protected, it can only be refered inside the model class, parents and children of model class.

When you refer to a model in your view object, the instance of model object is injected to the view, and you can't refer the protected properties directly. you need to fullfil the magic method __get in your model, for example:

```
public function __get($name){
    if (is_string($name && 'result' == $name)){
       return $this->_type;
    }
}
```

I think you need to read the documentation of Zend Framework to make it clear how models are injected in View object or View Model object.

Comment: You missed parenthesis in your `if` statement, and `is_string` function (sadly i can't edit your answer)

Comment: It's work :) I overrided __get method to verify if $name is what i pretend return from model, else it's call parent::__get($name). Thank you!

Comment: @bob just click on the **triangle** up the numbers of my answer, then you can give an upvote to my answers. it's nice to work for you.